# Xcode 9 - iOS 11 UITableView rows are empty

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios11

Ever since the new iOS 11 update, I have an app that will show blank tableview rows on the simulator and device. Even the row separators will not show for any of the rows that are supposed to be there. If I change the simulator to an older iOS version, the rows will show fine. No changes to code or storyboard.

The rows still have the data, meaning I can tap on one of the blank rows and it will execute the code and contain the information I was expecting.

It appears that other scenes that I have where the tableview is placed on a view and I don't use the built in text label work fine. Just this tableview class using the built in text label.

Here is my code for the tableview class...

```
@interface BunkPickTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation BunkPickTableViewController

@synthesize appDelegate, delegate, bunkPassedValue;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer tanGradient];
    bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];

    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    self.title = @"Bunk Codes";

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [appDelegate.bunkArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    }

    Bunk *bunkObj = [appDelegate.bunkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = bunkObj.bunkId;

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    Bunk *bunkObj  = [appDelegate.bunkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [delegate dismissBunkPop:bunkObj.bunkId];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

@end
```

[TableView Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cCa4.png)

Comment: When you step through the code, does `cell.textLabel.text` get the correct value?

Comment: It does, and I have breakpointed and checked that the correct number of rows are getting the correct information. All looks good.

Comment: I have a similar problem on a project that perfectly work on ios10 (all cells are now blank. Only group titles are normal). I'm looking at it.

Comment: Same issue here. Must be an iOS 11 bug. I fixed it by calling `tableView.reloadData()` inside `viewDidAppear()`. There's a little flash but better than not appearing. Also, I noticed the cells appear upon reuse (i.e. scroll them off screen and back on)

Comment: Reloaddata in viewDidAppear don’t work for me. I have a table view that works and some that are blank. But tableview that works, cell don’t reappear when they should be reuse...... But thanks

Comment: TableVIew.ReloadData did not work for me either. I have it in my viewWillAppear and tried adding a viewDidAppear with no luck...

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I was waiting for the ios11.1 to see if something changed, but it is not the case... so I planned to find an alternative way to introduce my tableviews.....

Comment: `[BackgroundLayer tanGradient]` what is this

Comment: @Kryckter, did you find any work around for this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue as well with IOS 11 showing blank cells.. but in IOS 10 was fine. My issue was that I was using a gradient which for whatever reason stopped the cell text from being shown. Removing the gradient resolved the blank cells.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because your `tableView` gets under `bgLayer`.

The problem seems to be in `self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0`. I was using `insertSubview` at index 0 and I had the same problem. This is probably a bug in iOS 11 - if your tableView is defined in storyboard, it always gets pushed to back.

**The best solution is to put the `bgLayer` inside the `tableView.backgroundView`.**

*NOTE:
You could also solve it by calling `sendSubviewToBack` on the `bgLayer` in `viewDidAppear`, but unfortunetaly, tableview cells are moving to back on every tableview reloaddata, so it is not a good solution.*

Comment: Well done. Thanks: I removed  my backgroundView 
        [self.tableView insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0]; And its working as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.tableView.bounds;
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor 
                    grayColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor 
                    lightGrayColor].CGColor];

UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] 
                          initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
[self setBackgroundView:bgView];
[bgView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

[self.tableView setBackgroundView:bgView];
```

Setting gradient layer for tableview's background view solved the problem for me. Upto iOS 10 we can directly insert sublayer to tableView but in iOS 11 layer should be inserted to UITableVIew's background view only.

Answer (score 0):

In tandem with the aforementioned tableview subviews manipulation, this problem can also occur if your project existed pre Xcode 9 and you then checked Use Safe Area Layout Guides on your storyboard. Try unchecking that and see if it works.